# jQuery invalid slideUp, slideDown effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slidedown, slideup

I have an problem with my small jQuery menu.

Here`s a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jvalousek/NthrX/

As you can see there, I need to show a specific part of code over hover my first visible menu. It seems that everything works fine, but if you try it, you can see some tricky effect which doesn't seems nice. It randomly generates slideUp, or slideDown...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sliding them all up! Target only the visible ones :

```
$('.selector').mouseenter(function() {
    var name = this.id + 'Text';
    $('.careerHint:visible').slideUp(function () {
        $("#" + name).slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

​

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NthrX/2/)

Answer (score 1):

remove the current item from selector in .slideUp

```
$('.careerHint').not($("#" + name)).slideUp(function () {
    $("#" + name).slideDown("fast");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NthrX/3/)